# Gradle with IntelliJ not loading PostgreSQL JDBC as a dependency

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, gradle

I am trying to setup IntelliJ alongwith Gradle and JOOQ for my next project. As of now, this is how my Gradle file looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jooq'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.jooq:jooq:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0'
    compile 'postgresql:postgresql:9.1-901-1.jdbc4'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'postgresql:postgresql:9.1-901-1.jdbc4'
        classpath 'com.github.ben-manes:gradle-jooq-plugin:0.5'
    }
}

jooq {
   ... snip ...
}
```

And this is how my external dependencies (in IntelliJ) show up:

[image: External dependency pane in IntelliJ] .

Somehow, Gradle is downloading and IntelliJ is recognizing the jooq and guava as part of my dependencies, but postgresql does not show up. So, while doing this works (using Guava, a dependency loaded from Gradle):

```
List<String> stringList = Lists.newArrayList();
```

This fails with a `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver").newInstance();
```

While doing a `./gradlew build`, I have seen gradle output the fact that it did download thr postgresql-9.1-901 jar from Maven Central, but I don't know where it keeps it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently, I really need to RTFM. I hadn't refreshed the dependencies from the Gradle tool window in IntelliJ after making changes to the Gradle script. Got it from here: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/synchronizing-changes-in-gradle-project-and-intellij-idea-project.html

Comment: I thought this runs automatically. Apparently it doesn't. Thanks 